# Querying 2/3 tables with one SQL statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I have three tables: `users, projects, user_project`

`user_project` contains `user_id, project_id` and `role_id`, where `user_id` and `project_id` are both primary keys connected to `projects.project_id` and `users.user_id`.

I want to get the the name and surname of all the users from the `users` table that has to do with a certain project from the `projects` table through `user_project`.

What SQL statement do I have to use? I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT 
    users.name, users.surname 
FROM users 
WHERE users.user_id = user_project.user_id AND projects.project_id = @parameter
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 and ASP.NET/VB.NET.

Db Diagram:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJloK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to **join** to your other tables - either from `Users` through `User_Project` all the way to `Projects` if you want to base your selection on something in the `Projects` table:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, u.surname 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_project up ON u.user_id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN project p ON p.project_id = up.project_id
WHERE p.project_name = 'something'
```

or at least to the link table, if you can use the `project_id` as criteria:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, u.surname 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_project up ON u.user_id = up.user_id
WHERE up.project_id = @parameter
```

**Update:** assuming your `Role` table is connected to `Users` through again a link table `Users_role` then you need this to select role name, too:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, u.surname,
    RoleName = r.Name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_project up ON u.user_id = up.user_id
INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON u.user_id = ur.user_id
INNER JOIN role r ON ur.role_id = r.role_id
WHERE up.project_id = @parameter
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the role_name from the role table? What modifications to the SQL would I need to do ?

Comment: @Brian: how is the `Role` table connected to the others? You need to (a) join the role table and then (b) select the `role.name` in your `SELECT`...

Comment: the Role table contains role_name, and role_id. user_projects also contains role_id. I tried `SELECT 
       users.name, users.surname, role.role_name
FROM   users role
       inner join user_project 
         on users.user_id = user_project.user_id
  inner join user_project
   on role.role_id = user_project.role_id
WHERE  user_project.project_id = 4
` to test it out but it did not work.

Comment: @Brian: updated my response - still not 100% sure if that's the way the tables are connected - adapt as needed ...

Comment: altough the SQL query executes successfully, no data is returned.

Comment: @Brian: sorry, I don't have your database in front of me, I can only **guess** what the issue could be .... maybe those users involved in that particular project don't have any roles assigned to them?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT users.name, users.surname
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_project up
ON u.user_id = up.user_id
WHERE up.project_id = @parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
       users.name, users.surname 
FROM   users 
       inner join user_project 
         on users.user_id = user_project.user_id
WHERE  user_project.project_id = @parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
SELECT users.name, users.surname 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_project ON user_project.user_id = users.user_id 
WHERE (user_project.project_id = @parameter)
```

The important line here is the line that starts `INNER JOIN`. You don't need the `project` table as the `project_id` column is in `user_project`. If you wanted to get the project name for example you would need the `project` table. You would do this by writing another `INNER JOIN`.

```
INNER JOIN project ON project.project_id = user_project.project_id
```

Now that you have joined you can access all the columns in the `project` table.